# fixing the size of data written to a text file from a console application

Tags: c#, text-files, console-application

i have a console application that writes data to a textfile. the text file gets printed out as a label.The question is can i be able to fix the size of a textfile that it must be the size of 13 lines one after the other so that the printer format doesnt have to change.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a fix number of lines in a text file, try using the "\r\n" escape sequence to create the desired number of lines.

Also consider using a library such as [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) for better formatting options.

Comment: I'd better use *System.Environment.NewLine()*.